# Regular Expression for Grammar = ({X, Y, Z}, {a, b}, X, {X → aY | bZ, Y → b | bZ, Z → a | aY})

Tags: regular-languages, automata, regular-expressions

2nd year college student here, I have trouble finding for the regular expression for that grammar, any help would help :D

Regular Language of the grammar:

X → aY → ab

X → bZ → ba

X → aY → abZ → aba

X → bZ → baY → bab

X → aY → abZ → abaY  → abab

X → bZ → baY → babZ → baba

X → aY → abZ → abaY  →ababZ → ababa

X → bZ → baY → babZ → babaY → babab

Regular Language: {ab, ba, aba, bab, abab, baba, ababa, babab, ...}

Comment: Try to convert the grammar into a finite state automaton. From there the construction of an expression is more intuitive.

Comment: I see, thank you for the comment! I'll try your suggestion :D

Answer (score 2):

You can apply Arden's lemma to solve your task even without constructing a DFA. The Arden lemma states that, given an equation $X = \Phi X\,|\,\Psi$, its minimal fixpoint (i.e., the minimal solution) is the regular expression $(\Phi)^*\Psi$.

Below I use the $+$ notation rather than $|$ to underline the connection with the equation systems in the linear algebra. Your system of the regular equations is now:

$$\begin{array}{l} X = aY + bZ  \\
Y = bZ + b \\
Z = aY + a 
\end{array}
$$

The variable $X$ is not involved in any recursion, thus the regular expression for it is simply an alternative of the two regexps $aY\,|\,bZ$. To determine them, you can substitute the equation for $Z$ to the $Z$ occurrence in the equation $Y = bZ + b$ and apply Arden's lemma. The overall technique is exactly the same as in the linear algebra.